# Python: Print float with higer precision than 51 decimals

Tags: python, floating-point

I'm trying to get an extremely precise answer out of python. But i can't go higher up than 51 decimals. I'm running a function using numpy(liek arccos and sqrt) to return the time.

This is how i print:

```
print("{0:.51}".format(time))
```

If i increase the number 51, nothing happens.. This is what it prints:

```
0.451301790031115590551280547515489161014556884765625
```

Would love your input.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you doing that requires precision past 51 decimal places?

Comment: NumPy does not offer anywhere near 51-digit precision. If you want arbitrary-precision arithmetic, use an arbitrary-precision arithmetic library, not NumPy.

Comment: I'm trying to calculate the collision time of dropping a mass of 1 kg in vacum. Andt the collision time  of 2 kg in vacum. The difference in mass will cause the earth to accelerate just slightly up towards the mass.. So it will be a little quicker @ChrisRisley

Comment: You could use the [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) module.

Comment: Thanks @ljeabmreosn it seems like the module can't do arccos it seems

Comment: If I recall correctly, NumPy and Python use an underlying floating-point type of the system it is running on. Commonly, this is the IEEE 754 64-bit binary format. This format has a precision of less than one part in 2**53 (about 9e15). The mass of the Earth is about 5.97e24 kg. Adding the acceleration due to a kilogram’s gravity to the acceleration due to Earth’s gravity is therefore a much smaller change than the floating-point format can accommodate.

Comment: The reason Python will not print any more digits is those digits already show the exact value of the floating-point number. All further digits would be zero.

Comment: Most of those 51 digits will be inaccurate, too. Try `print("{0:.51}".format(1/3))`.

Comment: @MarkRansom: As specified by the IEEE 754 standard, those digits are exactly correct. They show the represented value exactly (or, if fewer digits are printed, correctly rounded), if the implementation conforms to IEEE 754. The error in the example you show occurs in the division, not in the printing or the representation. This distinction is important for analyzing and designing floating-point operations. Treating the error as in the representation rather than the operation leads to incorrect expectations or models of computation.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I understand your point completely, but I emphasize this for our readers: just because you can see all those digits does *not* make them all meaningful. A naive person could think they're all accurate.